# Question on yeast quality?

Tags: bread, yeast

I'm about to buy some ingreadients for a bread recipe which calls for quick yeast.  I looked up some info and basically it looks like quick yeast is instant yeast, so first off if I could get a varification on that, that would be great.  But assuming they are the same leads me to my actual question.  I'm looking at two yeast products to buy, both look like their from France.  One is almost two and a half time more expensive, but the more expensive one is the exact same product used in the recipe.  So I'm wondering does it make a difference?  Here are the two products:

[Saf Instant Yeast, 1 Pound Pouch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001CXUHW)

[Doves Farm Quick Yeast (125g)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JZ41VKK)

Comment: In much of the world, there's plenty of perfectly good yeast you can buy at the grocery store too, no real need to shop around for specific brands.

Comment: If you're not baking bread very often, be warned that it can take a while to get through a 1lb bag of yeast.  (as it takes me a year or so, I transfer mine to a glass jar, and keep it in the fridge ... it almost fully fits in a 24oz jar).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, quick yeast and instant yeast are the same thing.  It doesn't have to be proofed in warm water before being mixed into the dough.

SAF instant yeast is a good product, so personally, I wouldn't spend so much more for a specialty brand.  Both brands contain yeast and an emulsifier, and SAF also contains ascorbic acid (which acts as a dough conditioner).

Resources:

- [SAF Instant](http://www.lsaf.com/products/bakers-yeast-products/dry-yeast/saf-instant-red)
- [Doves Farm](https://www.dovesfarm.co.uk/flour-and-ingredients/quick-yeast-1x125g/)
- [Ascorbic Acid](http://www.sustainweb.org/realbread/ascorbic_acid/#e300_function)